# Lua '=' excpected error help needed

Tags: lua

So I was attempting to make a lua script but came back with an error and it would be nice if someone could help me out with this!

Here the code:

```
do
local a = 5
function fly()
    if a = 5 then
        print("a = 5")
        return a
    if a = 5 then
        a = a - 1
        if a = 4 then
            print("It works!")
    else
        print("No work :(")
        return a
    end
end


print(fly())
print("done")
```

Comment: The equality operator is `==`, not `=`. `=` is assignment, which can't be used as an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If needs to be closed by else, elseif or end.

```
local a = 5

function fly()
    if a == 5 then -- == instead of =
        print("a = 5")
        return a
    end --added a end
    if a == 5 then -- == instead of =
        a = a - 1
        if a == 4 then -- == instead of =
            print("It works!")
        end --added a end
    else
        print("No work :(")
        return a
    end
end


print(fly())
print("done")
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `if a = 5 then` you need to be using `if a == 5 then`. See [Relational Operators](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.3) section in the documentation.